# Why my javascript statement works properly in local but not in my QA enviroment?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

```js
//Begin -----
var listItems = $(".row.entry.withPreviewImage > div > .col3 > div > p > input");

if (listItems.length == 0){
  listItems= $('div[id^="description_container_"]')
              .find('input[id^="availabilityFlag"]');
}

var partNumber     = null
  , qty            = null
  , outofStockFlag = false;
if (listItems){
  for (var i=0;i < listItems.length; i++){
    if (listItems[i].value == 'outofStock'){
      partNumber = $(".row.entry.withPreviewImage")
                    .find(".itemspecs.cell > span")[i].innerHTML;
      qty = $(".row.entry.withPreviewImage")
                    .find(".QTY.cell").find(".quantity_input")[i].value;
        
      MessageHelper.displayErrorMessage(Utils.getLocalizationMessage("OUT_OF_STOCK"));
      outofStockFlag = true;
      return;
    }
  }
}
//more code....
```

In my local enviroment of testing when i debug the code and enter inside the for statement, the `return;` works properly and stop the execution of next actions.
But in my QA enviroment(other external server where the .war is deployed), in the moment of entering to this exact for statement until de same `return;` just dont stop, and all the next functions are executed.
Someone know any posible motive of this to happen?

Comment: Other than "you're calling the function multiple times", not really.

Comment: what do you mean? @Bergi

Comment: try `for (let i=0;i < listItems.length; i++) {`

Comment: It means that this doesn't happen - at least with the code you posted - and there's something else wrong. What exactly made you assume that the function would continue to run after the `return` statement was executed?

Comment: Because I debug inside the for and when step in return; the code continue running and others js function are executed. @Bergi all this happen in execution time, and in my local environment this don't happens :/